# Entity framework CTP5 Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I am trying to test the Entity Framework CTP 5 Code First with an existing table.

1. I defined the model class and DbContext and ran the application. It created the database and table.
2. I dropped `EdmMetadata` table from the database.
3. Added `Trusted_Connection=true;Persist Security Info=True` in my connection string.
4. When I run the application again, it gives me this error.

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code

Message=Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not 
contain model metadata.

Source=EntityFramework
```

How can I make this application run without `EdmMetadata` table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use EdmMetadata table try to add this into your `DbContext` derived class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
}
```

Comment: I added this method and ran the problem I got this error. `[NotSupportedException: Model compatibility cannot be checked because the EdmMetadata type was not included in the model.  Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the ModelBuilder conventions.]
`          I dropped and ran the application it didn't create Edmmetadata table