# Entity Framework Code First not updating DB when there are conflicts

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a strange problem with EF. I've got it creating and updating my database with the following code:

In Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Project.Models.Datacontext, Configuration>());
```

In Migrations/Configuration:

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

My understanding is that AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed should drop tables and re-create them, even if it means data loss.

Now for the most part this all works. However, if I have a field that is a nvarchar (string) with text in it (say "abcd"). If I change this field to an integer data type, EF does nothing with the DB and the app doesn't work.

I would have thought it would drop the table, re-create it and for that record with abcd it's bad luck? Or have I misinterpreted? Or am I missing code?

Comment: do `update-database -verbose` and see what the output is. That might give you a clue as to whats going on. There could be a gazillion things here. Paste whatever message you get here and then someone might be able to help.

Comment: For future googlers http://stackoverflow.com/a/13498896/19308 may give additional useful information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code-First: How to manually update the database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618587/entity-framework-code-first-how-to-manually-update-the-database)