# Entity Framework 5 / Firebird / Code first database creation

Tags: entity-framework-5, firebird2.5

I am trying to use Entity Framework 5, code first, to create a database using the Firebird provider, but I get the following error:

> Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Model compatibility can only be checked for databases created using Code First or Code First Migrations.

Does Firebird not support the creation of the database using a code first model?

Comment: This seems unrelated to Firebird, but to the way you configure the dbContext class and how you created the database. Take a look, for example, to this quiestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150731/entity-framework-ctp5-model-compatibility-cannot-be-checked-because-the-database

Comment: I am not using an existing table, and my initializer is DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges

Comment: The problem goes away when I delete the database... Unfortunatly there are other errors in the recreate sql